# Strcmp() function realization on C

Tags: c

I need to make an strcmp function by myself, using operations with pointers. That's what I got:

```
int mystrcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    while ('\0' != *str1 && *str1 == *str2) {
        str1 += 1;
        str2++;
    }
    int result1 = (uint8_t)(*str2) - (uint8_t)(*str1); // I need (uint8_t) to use it with Russian symbols.
    return result1;
}
```

But my tutor told me that there are small mistake in my code. I spend really lot of time making tests, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Why are you using `str1 += 1` but `str2++`? Also, you are not checking for the possibility that `str2` is shorter than `str1`.

Comment: Please don't alter the code: does your *actual code* have `str1++` or  `str1 += 1`?

Comment: I forgot to change it back after testing, my code has str1++.

Comment: Write down 4 basic test cases. Compare strings that are the same; that are the same length, but different text; where str1 is longer than str2; where str2 is longer than str1.  Run each of those tests in your code, and check the results.  You will find your mistake quickly, and be a better programmer for having tested your code.

Comment: @EdHeal it is ok, but only for ASCII symbols. When I'm working with non ASCII ("абв", "абвг") it is not working.

Comment: I guess he is using an 8-bit ASCII extension where the lower half of the table is ASCII and the top half are Russian symbols. The comparison works only when the top half are treated as values 128-255.

Comment: I thought yes, but i don't know how to check it. ("абв", "абвг") is analog to ("abc", "abcd"), but when i use int the result is different.

Comment: It is not specified whether `char` should be unsigned or signed, but many implementation use a signed char, so the Russian symbols in the range 128 to 255 are treated as -128 to -1. This will reverse the comparison.

Comment: TBH I can't find any mistakes in this. After looking closely at this code I don't notice anything wrong or useless. Could be your tutor is wrong or talking about another part of the code.

Comment: @EliSadoff: when `str2` is shorter than `str1`, the `\0` in `str2` will stop the loop because `str1` will not have a `'\0'` there

Comment: The sign of your result is reversed from what's normal, isn't it?  The `uint8_t` casts are fine; it forces the possibly-signed `char` values to positive `uint8_t` values, which are then promoted to `int` before the subtraction (normal type promotions).  But if the character that differs is `'a'` in `str1` and `'b'` in `str2`, you will return a positive value when you should return a negative.

Comment: @MOehm  `char` as a `signed char` or `unsigned char` should not reverse the comparison as `strcmp()` is specified to compare the characters as `unsigned char` even if `char` is a `signed char`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, you are right, the relative order of two top-half chars stays the same. It will only reverse the comparison of two chars from different halves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this answer the question of what you're doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <string.h>

int mystrcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2);

int main(void)
{
    char* javascript = "JavaScript";
    char* java = "Java";

    printf("%d\n", mystrcmp(javascript, java));
    printf("%d\n", strcmp(javascript, java));
    return 0;
}

int mystrcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
    while ('\0' != *str1 && *str1 == *str2) {
        str1 += 1;
        str2++;
    }
    int result1 = (uint8_t)(*str2) - (uint8_t)(*str1); // I need (uint8_t) to use it with Russian symbols.
    return result1;
}
```

Output:

```
-83
 83
```

---

I'll **propose a quick fix**:

Change

```
int result1 = (uint8_t)(*str2) - (uint8_t)(*str1);
```

To

```
int result1 =  (uint8_t)(*str1) - (uint8_t)(*str2);
```

---

**And why you were wrong:**

The return values of `strcmp()` should be:

> if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
>
> if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
>
> if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

**And you were doing exactly the opposite.**

Answer (score 5):

[@yLaguardia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41047541/2410359) well answered the order problem.

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

> The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`. C11dr §7.24.4.2 3

---

Using `uint8_t` is fine for the vast majority of cases.  Rare machines do not use 8-bit `char`, so `uint8_t` is not available.  In any case, it is not needed as `unsigned char` handles the required *unsigned* compare.  (See below about unsigned compare.)

```
int result1 = 
    ((unsigned char)*str1 - (unsigned char)*str2);
```

Even higher portable code would use the following to handle when `char` range and `unsigned` range match as well as all other `char, unsigned char, int, unsigned` sizes/ranges.

```
int result1 = 
    ((unsigned char)*str1 > (unsigned char)*str2) - 
    ((unsigned char)*str1 < (unsigned char)*str2);
```

---

`strcmp()` is defined as treating each character as `unsigned char`, regardless if `char` is signed or unsigned.

> ... each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type
>   `unsigned char` ... C11 §7.24.1 3

---

Should the `char` be ASCII or not is not relevant to the coding of `strcmp()`.  Of course under different character encoding, different results may occur.  Example: `strcmp("A", "a")` may result in a positive answer (seldom used [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) with one encoding, but negative ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) on another.